# How do the OCaml operators < and > work with non-integer types?

Tags: operators, ocaml, comparison-operators

I'm curious how the greater than (>) and less than (<) operators work with types that are not int, float, or double in OCaml.

For instance, I was able to discover that string "a" > "b" but is there some reference that lists the conventions for all non-numerical data types. Furthermore, how do these operators work across types? e.g. Is "a" > true or is "a" < true?

Finally, how would these work across a user-defined data type?

Thanks!

Comment: ocaml operators for strings compares their case sensitivity.

Comment: and ` string a<string b ` is true when string a comes before string b in dictionary order.

Comment: The C++ tag was not needed. I have removed it.

Answer (score 8):

The OCaml `<`, `>`, `<=`, `>=` operators only work with two values of the same type, so the expression `"a" > true` is invalid. However, they work for all types (with caveats below). You can find the definitions of these operators in the [`Stdlib`](https://v2.ocaml.org/releases/4.14/api/Stdlib.html) module (formerly known as Pervasives).

The order for these operators is defined only for simple values (integers, characters, strings, byte sequences, and floating). In these cases the documentation says they give "the usual ordering".

The usual ordering for strings and byte sequences is lexicographic order. For strings, case is significant.

For compound values the order is only guaranteed to be consistent with `=` and to be a consistent ordering.

As far as I can see, order is not defined for simple user-defined types like `type abc = A | B | C`. I didn't expect this to be the case, but that's what I see in the documentation. In practice, the values of constant constructors like `A`, `B`, `C`, will be ordered in the order of declaration with the first value the smallest.

I also don't see a definition of the order between `false` and `true`. Again, this is surprising. In practice, `false` is less than `true`.

It is worth noting that comparisons between cyclic values is not guaranteed to terminate. Also, comparison between values that contain functions may raise an exception. These can cause unexpected problems, sometimes serious ones.

```
$ ocaml
        OCaml version 4.02.1

# (+) < (+);;
Exception: Invalid_argument "equal: functional value".
# let rec cycle = 1 :: cycle;;
val cycle : int list = [1; <cycle>]
# cycle < cycle;;
(( Does not terminate ))
```

Comment: Also, constant constructors are smaller than non-constant ones, and those are ordered by their order of declaration. Tuples also have lexicographic ordering. Arrays seem to be ordered by size then by lexicographic ordering.

Comment: These are true, but aren't documented. So in theory they could change with the next release of OCaml.

Comment: Also undocumented, lists are lexicographically ordered. Though this result might be derived simply from having the constant empty-list constructor be ordered before the non-constant cons constructor, and then otherwise the data of the cons being lexicographically ordered as a tuple.

Comment: To have undocumented orderings seems problematic in a language like OCaml that tries to avoid runtime surprises as much as is practical. I'm surprised that OCaml doesn't just throw an exception in this case. Polymorphic mathematical operators are very odd things in OCaml anyway.

Comment: Throw an exception in what case?