# OCaml, comparing int lists using < > = operators

Tags: list, types, comparison, operators, ocaml

Question:

What is the logic behind comparing int lists using <, >, =? What about 'a lists?

Code:

`# let x = [1] > [1]
val x : bool = false`

`# let x = [1;2] > [1]
val x : bool = true`

`# let x = [1;2] > [2;1]
val x : bool = false`

`# let x = [true;false] < [true;true]
val x : bool = true`

Follow up questions:

- when comparing two lists, how does the comparison work if the lists are not the same length? if the lists don't contain elements of the same type?

Comment: This seems to be addressed in answers to another question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31152244/how-do-the-ocaml-operators-and-work-with-non-integer-types

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do the OCaml operators < and > work with non-integer types?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31152244/how-do-the-ocaml-operators-and-work-with-non-integer-types)

Answer (score 0):

An ocaml list is represented by

```
type 'a my_list = Nil | Cons of 'a * 'a my_list
```

The Nil constructor is represented as an integer of value 0 while the Cons is a pointer to a block with tag 0 and 2 fields.

The < > = operators consider Nil < Cons. So if the lists are not the same length then the shorter list is smaller.

Comparison is always between the same types so lists of different types can't be compared (without Obj.magic).